# How do you extract time-domain amplitudes from real signal with python FFT tools?

Tags: python, numpy, fft

I'm working on a problem where I would like to extract and compare the time domain amplitudes of two different signals at each frequency. The signals are real world, so have noise, and multiple frequencies, so I'm trying to work in the FFT world.

I wrote a function to take the FFT of a dataset, and return the amplitudes. This seems to work okay for a simulated pure sin wave, but when performed on actual datasets, the amplitudes are always attenuated by some amount.

```
def amplitudePowerSpectrum(time,data):
    dt = np.zeros(time.size-1,)
    avgdt = np.mean(time[1:-1] - time[0:-2])
    sampFreq = 1.0/(avedt)
    nyquistFreq = sampFreq/2.0  

    FFTData = np.abs(scipy.fftpack.fft(data))   
    ## Only care about positive frequencies
    FFTData = FFTData[0:len(FFTData)/2]
    ## This is how we get the power spectrum in terms of time-domain amplitudes
    amplitudeSpectrum = FFTData/len(FFTData)

    freqsData = scipy.fftpack.fftfreq(data.size, avgdt)
    freq = freqsData[0:len(freqsData)/2]        

    return (freq,amplitudeSpectrum,(sampFreq,nyquistFreq))
```

Here is a plot of a raw dataset, followed by one of the computed amplitude spectrum.As you can see, there are two specifically different frequencies, with other noise on top. 
[image: Time Domain]

[image: Frequency Domain Amplitudes]

I'd expect the amplitudes in figure 2 to match the time domain amplitudes in figure 1. But they are attenuated by a pretty decent factor. The end goal is a scale factor between the input (blue) and output (red) signals at each frequency.

First, is obataining time domain amplitudes accurately possible in the Fourrier domain on real datasets? If so, what am I missing? I'm working with python numpy and scipy packages

Comment: Numpys fft assumes that dt is the same for all your data. If they are not I would recommend using np.interp.

Comment: Maybe this is because of the typo in line four, where you reference a variable `avedt`, which is not declared in the scope of your function.  Also, it is not clear what your variable `time` is. Furthermore, your sample frequency should equal `1/len(data)`